# How to hide default addthis share buttons when use costom?

Tags: addthis

I want to use costom buttons for share.

My code:

```
    <div
      class="share-article__list addthis_inline_share_toolbox"
    >
      <a class="addthis_button_facebook share-article__item ">
        <svg-icon
          class="share-article__icon"
          name="social-networks/facebook-wr"
          width="8"
          height="15"
        />
      </a>
      <a class="share-article__item addthis_button_twitter">
        <svg-icon
          class="share-article__icon"
          name="social-networks/twitter-wr"
          width="15"
          height="12"
        />
      </a>
      <a class="share-article__item addthis_button_vk">
        <svg-icon
          class="share-article__icon"
          name="social-networks/vk-wr"
          width="18"
          height="10"
        />
      </a>
    </div>
```

When I open page, I have got this
[image]

How to turn off default buttons?

Answer (score 0):

This can be controlled through the AddThis dashboard.
Under the **Tools > Website Tools** section, make sure that the social sharing tool you plan to use is switched on.

Once that's done, click through to it, select **Sharing Services**, and select the option ***Selected By You***.

From here, remove all the social media options and click **Update Tool**.

Now that your tool's settings have been updated, click **Get The Code** in the top-right, and make sure that your AddThis embed code is included on your website.

Now when you refresh, the social icons should no longer appear.